# Spring framework with @Configuration - alternative to aop:configure

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

In "good old" XML-style of config, it was easy to separate the aspect from the pointcut: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-schema-advice
which was good if you as a framework developer would like to offer the aspect, but let the application programmers provide the pointcut - typically for monitoring. How to do the same with `@Configuration` (and avoid @Importing XML-based contexts).

Yes, it can be done by providing annotations to use in the pointcut - but I favour to let the developers have the option of doing type/package matching without having to annotate all over the place, it is also easier to match consistently because they won't forget to add an annotation.

Comment: This is a good question. But thinking aloud (if I may), I am wondering what is so bad about using XML config for exactly that reason in addition to annotation-based config for the rest. Because if you do not use XML, you will need to use annotations or abstract aspects which your devs can subclass. Both variants incur the need for your devs to compile Java code. If that is okay for you, go for it. Otherwise, use XML. Do you have a third option in mind? If so, which one? Would e.g. a *.properties file be any better than an XML file?